# Formula for $\prod\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{k+z}\right)^{k+z+\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let $\displaystyle ~(-1)^z:=e^{i\pi z}~$ for $~z\in\mathbb{C} ~\land~\Re(z)\geq 0~$ .

$\displaystyle A(z):=\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{k+z}\right)^{k+z+\frac{1}{2}}~$ for $~z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}~$ .

From that follows immediately $\displaystyle ~A(-z)\,A(z)=\prod\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{k+z}\right)^{k+z+\frac{1}{2}}~$ .

Question: $~$ How can we proof

> $$A(-z)\,A(z)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-i2\pi z}} ~~, \hspace{5mm}\Re(z)\geq 0 \hspace{1cm} ?$$

---

*Background:*

Proof of the well-known Euler’s Infinite Product for the Sine using the Stirling formula.

$\displaystyle F(z) := \Gamma(z+1) = \left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z\sqrt{2\pi z}\,A(z)$

Formal extension:  $\enspace\displaystyle F(-z):=\left(-\frac{z}{e}\right)^{-z}\sqrt{-2\pi z}\,A(-z)$

We get $\enspace\displaystyle F(-z) = e^{i\pi\left(-z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^{-z}\sqrt{2\pi z}\,A(-z) = \frac{e^{i\pi\left(-z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}}{1-e^{-i2\pi z}}\left(\frac{e}{z}\right)^z\frac{\sqrt{2\pi z}}{A(z)} = 
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi z}}{2A(z)\sin(\pi z)}\left(\frac{e}{z}\right)^z$

and therefore $\enspace\displaystyle F(-z)\,F(z) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi z}}{2\,A(z)\sin(\pi z)}\left(\frac{e}{z}\right)^z \cdot \left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z\sqrt{2\pi z}\,A(z) = \frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}~$ .

---

EDIT:

After a discussion with *Diger*, I think it's a problem to use the definition of $A(z)$ for $A(-z)$ . It comes from the interpretation of $(-1)^{-z}$ and $(\frac{1}{-1})^z$ . It makes sense to define:

$$A(z):=\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{e}\frac{(k+z+1)^{k+z+\frac{1}{2}}}{(k+z)^{k+z+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

EDIT 2: $~~$*Solution*

J. R. Quine, S. H. Heydari and R. Y. Song are discussing *Zeta Regularized Products* [here](http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/files/QuineZetaRegularization.pdf).

On page 226, example $10$, is shown how my question could be answered.

Comment: Since $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e,$$I am now sure in which summability sense your product is considered.

Comment: @SangchulLee : A big sorry, I forgot to place $e$ in the product. Thanks for the hint. Now it's o.k. .

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate $\log A(z)$ explicitly, by diferentiating with respect to $z$ two times and carrying out the summation.

You'll then obtain $$\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}z^2} \, \log A(z) = \Psi'(z) - \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{2z^2} \\ 
\Longrightarrow \quad \log A(z) = \log \Gamma(z+1) + z - z\log z - \log \sqrt{z} + c_1 z + c_2 \, .$$

By comparing the limit value for $z \rightarrow \infty$ of the original sum (which is $0$), you will need $c_1=0$ and $c_2=-\log\sqrt{2\pi}$, so $$\log A(z) = \log \Gamma(z+1) + z - z\log z - \log \sqrt{2\pi z} \\ A(z) = \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} \left(\frac{e}{z}\right)^z \, .$$ I presume you can use this backwards to prove your equality. Note that the exponent $1/2$ is crucial in the sum/product. For any other value the sum/product diverges.

---

To be honest I still don't know what you precisely want :-(. Have you tried
\begin{align}
&\qquad \prod_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{e} \, \frac{(k+z+1)^{k+z+1/2}}{(k+z)^{k+z+1/2}} \\
&=(1+N+z)^{N+z+1/2} (z-N)^{N-z+1/2} \frac{e^{-2N-1}}{z} \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{z^2-k^2} \\
&=\left(1+\frac{z+1}{N}\right)^{N+z+1/2} N^{N+z+1/2} \cdot \left(1-\frac{z}{N}\right)^{N-z+1/2} N^{N-z+1/2} \\ &\quad \cdot (-1)^{1/2-z} \, \frac{e^{-2N-1}}{z} \cdot \frac{1}{N!^2} \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z}{k}\right)^2} \\
&\sim \frac{(-1)^{1/2-z}}{2\pi z}  \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z}{k}\right)^2} \\
&= \frac{i e^{-i\pi z}}{2\sin(\pi z)} = \frac{1}{1-e^{i2\pi z}} \, ?
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But we are in a circle here. That $A(z)$ is part of $\Gamma(z+1)$ is well known and presupposed. Nevertheless, your comment is of course helpful in understanding the connection between $A(z)$ and the Gamma function.

Comment: Well then I don't understand your question... What do you mean by "is part of" is well known? Did you know this precise relation before? If not, then you can use this now to prove your yellow objective by the Gamma reflection formula.

Comment: By Eulers formula for the Gamma function, do you mean $$\Gamma(z+1) = \left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z\sqrt{2\pi z}\,A(z) \, ?$$

Comment: Not sure that is what you are looking for...

Comment: So you don't want to use $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z}{k}\right)^2} = \frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}\, ?$$

Comment: The only thing I can more or less say here while abiding by your "theme" is that after using the manipulations in the second part above for $$A(-z)A(z) = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{e} \, \frac{(k+z+1)^{k+z+1/2}}{(k+z)^{k+z+1/2}} \, ,$$ the remaining product (as is the well known one Euler product for the sine) identifies uniquely the function with the same spectrum of zeros/poles. This is just the Weierstrass factorization theorem.

Comment: Isn't that what I was doing in the second part? Just manipulating to the proper form.

Comment: I think mine is correct. Checking with a CAS your minus sign in the exponent doesn't agree with the numerics. The product developement for the sine arises just naturally. Your function is not real for real $z$, but the product expansion is.

Comment: Do you need a straight forward derivation for the product development of the sine, or does the Weierstrass argument suffice?

Comment: What is wrong there? Seems correct to me (though in your comment above it should be $(-1)^{N-z+1/2}$ instead of $(-1)^{z+1/2}$).

Comment: I think the problem is more $$\prod_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{e} \, \left(\frac{k+z+1}{k+z}\right)^{k+z+1/2} \neq \prod_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{e} \, \frac{(k+z+1)^{k+z+1/2}}{(k+z)^{k+z+1/2}}$$ which I overjumped and that introduces the phase issues. The term giving rise to this is the unique $k$ for which $k+z<0$ while $k+z+1>0$. That is $$\prod_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{e} \, \left(\frac{k+z+1}{k+z}\right)^{k+z+1/2} = \left(-1\right)^{2\left(-\lceil z \rceil+z+1/2\right)} \prod_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{e} \, \frac{(k+z+1)^{k+z+1/2}}{(k+z)^{k+z+1/2}}$$ with $N>R(z)$. Other than that, the further steps should be correct.

Comment: Then $$\frac{(-1)^{2z+1}}{1-e^{i2\pi z}}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-i2\pi z}}\,. $$

Comment: The first equality is not correct for every $k+z$...

Comment: Formal extension for $A(-z)$ based on the definition of $A(z)$ :  $\enspace\displaystyle F(-z):=\left(-\frac{z}{e}\right)^{-z}\sqrt{-2\pi z}\,A(-z)$ --- Perhaps wrong ? At the moment I have not the possibility to check this. A counter example would be the best.

Comment: Well then have fun proving it, without doing any manipulations ;)

Comment: Yeah, but if you introduce that definition, why don't you actually work with it? If $k+z<0$ and $k+z+1>0$ then $\arg\left(\left(\frac{k+z+1}{k+z}\right)^{k+z+1/2}\right) =\pi(k+z+1/2)$ for real $z$ by your definition. On the other hand $\arg\left( \frac{(k+z+1)^{k+z+1/2}}{(k+z)^{k+z+1/2}} \right) = -\pi(k+z+1/2)$, so there is not that much magic to it, or?

Comment: You have convinced me that there is a problem with the definition of $A(z)$, it's not usable for $A(-z)$ . Please delete your last comments, as I have done, because it becomes too much text here. ;)